# root.config attribute error Python/Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

So i keep getting this problem when i try to run my code. i am new to programming so im not really sure what to do. 
Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def donothing():
    print "Ok ok i wont.."

root = Tk()

menu = Menu(root)
root.conifig(menu=menu)

submenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subemenu)
submenu.add_command(label="New project...", command=donothing)
submenu.add_command(label="save", command=donothing)
submenu.add_separator()
submenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=donothing)

editmenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
editmenu.add_command(label="Redo", command=donothing)


root.mainloop()
```

Heres the problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui7.py", line 9, in <module>
    root.conifig(menu=menu)
  File 


"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/li 
    b-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1898, in __getattr__
        return getattr(self.tk, attr)
    AttributeError: conifig
```

Comment: `config` is mistyped as `conifig`.

Comment: First step in debugging is to read the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter has no attribute `conifig` but rather `config` do well to check the `tkinter` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) to check other attribute of tkinter.

```
from Tkinter import *

def donothing():
  print "Ok ok i wont.."

root = Tk()

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

submenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=submenu)
submenu.add_command(label="New project...", command=donothing)
submenu.add_command(label="save", command=donothing)
submenu.add_separator()
submenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=donothing)

editmenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
editmenu.add_command(label="Redo", command=donothing)


root.mainloop()
```